# How to create list of dictionaries from multiple columns in PySpark where key is a column name and value is that column's value?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider an example dataframe, say `df`:

```
user_id | item_id | item_param1 | item_param2 |
  1          a           10            20
  1          b           30            40
  2          b           50            60
  2          c           70            80
```

From this dataframe `df`, I want to collect all `items` and their properties `item_paramX` for every `user_id` in a single row, so output would be:

```
user_id |    values
------------------------------------------------
  1     |   [{'a': {'item_param1': 10, 'item_param2': 20}}, {'b': {'item_param1': 30, 'item_param2': 40}}]
  2     |   [{'b': {'item_param1': 50, 'item_param2': 60}}, {'c': {'item_param1': 70, 'item_param2': 80}}]
```

I will need to use `groupBy('user_id')` and then some form of `collect_list` to get the list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collect_list` on a map of `item_id -> struct`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('user_id').agg(
    F.to_json(
        F.collect_list(
            F.create_map(
                'item_id', 
                F.struct('item_param1', 'item_param2')
            )
        )
    ).alias('values')
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|user_id|values                                                                               |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1      |[{"a":{"item_param1":10,"item_param2":20}},{"b":{"item_param1":30,"item_param2":40}}]|
|2      |[{"b":{"item_param1":50,"item_param2":60}},{"c":{"item_param1":70,"item_param2":80}}]|
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```